# Where is Performance Tuner in Glassfish 4? (optimizing for Raspberry PI)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, raspberry-pi

I can`t find Performance Tuner in Glassfish 4. Where I can find it? I want to optimize performance of Glassfish 4 for Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 1):

The Performance Tuner is only included in the Oracle version of Glassfish (not in the community edition).